# JPA downcast: criteria treat vs JPQL treat

Tags: jpa, jpql, criteria

JPQL and Criteria API:

```
SELECT o
FROM Order o JOIN TREAT(o.product AS Book) b

CriteriaQuery<Order> query = cb.createQuery(Order.class);
Root<order> root = query.from(Order.class)
Join product = root.join("product");
Join book = cb.treat(product, Book.class);
query.select(root);
```

Are they the same query? For criteria API, cb.treat(...) creates a new instance
of Join (book), but the join (book) is not used in Query.

For JPQL, the root joins to the treated JOIN (book).